# Processing Java, how can I toggle full screen?

Tags: java, processing

I'd like to interactively change the screen size of my PApplet window, i'm unsure of how to do that. Originally I thought, I'd declare a boolean fullscreen and inside the settings method: if fullscreen was true the size would be set to fullScreen() or else it'd be a smaller fixed size. Clicking a button would trigger the fullscreen boolean to change from false to true or true to false. However, this doesn't work for me. I understand that this is due to the fact that the settings method is not called again once the canvas is redrawn.

Can anyone solve this issue?

Comment: You should paste some code of what you have tried in your question

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. In the future, please try to post a [mcve] showing what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `surface` variable, which gives access to functions that let you change the size and position of your sketch's window.

Particularly:

- `surface.setResizable(true)` will allow your users to resize the window.
- `surface.setSize(500, 500)` will change the size of the window to 500x500.

You can find more info [here](https://processing.github.io/processing-javadocs/core/processing/core/PSurface.html).